# Two different letter style in inline equation

Tags: fonts

In the following inline equation I am getting x of two different styles. How can I fix that ?

```
$A_{x}B_{1-x}$
```

Following is the image of the generated output

[image]

I use org-mode to do pdf latex export. To create a minimal example, I wrote just A_{x}B_{1-x} in an org-mode file and exported it to pdf. Following is the content of the generated .tex file. There was no error.

```
% Created 2013-04-16 Tue 22:51
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\tolerance=1000
\providecommand{\alert}[1]{\textbf{#1}}

\title{A$_{x}$B$_{\mathrm{1-x}}$}
\author{ME}
\date{\today}
\hypersetup{
  pdfkeywords={},
  pdfsubject={},
  pdfcreator={Emacs Org-mode version 7.9.3f}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\tableofcontents
\vspace*{1cm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: When (or even before) you post the image please show a minimum working example (MWE) - the shortest document you can construct that illustrates the problem. I couldn't reproduce it with just `$A_{x}B_{1-x}$` in the document, no packages.

Comment: Do you get errors as well? You probably have syntax errors in your tex file. By the way, submit a *minimum working example*.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). The `\mathrm` is the cause of the second `x` being upright.

Comment: If you want roman `A` and `B` you should be doing it this way: `$\mathrm{A}_{x}\mathrm{B}_{1-x}$` rather than jump in and out of math mode.

Answer (score 3):

The correct syntax should be

```
\title{$A_{x}B_{1-x}$}
```

with a single formula and no `\mathrm`, which is the cause for the upright “x”.